# How long until light reaches me if I travel away from a point?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

Let's assume that:

1. I'm 1 light year away from some point in space
2. I'm travelling away from that point at 0.5c (or whatever fraction of the speed of light it takes for relativity to play a big role)
3. A photon is shot from the point exactly in my direction

**How long would it take for the photon to actually reach me?**

I know I can do a naive calculation along the lines of:

1. The photon is travelling toward me at 1c
2. I am moving away at 0.5c
3. The different in speed is 0.5c
4. So it will take the photon 2 years to cross the 1 light year to reach me.

But how different could the actual answer be when we take into account relativity or the expansion of the universe?

Comment: Sorry, but this question falls under our policy of [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) questions.

Comment: Also, it's a bit vague, because the times & distances depend on the frame you measure them in, i.e., the light source frame and the spaceship frame.

Comment: I voted to reopen because I don't understand why this was closed. It seems like people treat a question as homework-like just for having specific numbers in it – but in this case the numbers are clearly just examples, and I don't think it's even necessary to edit the question to remove them.

Comment: Tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: I want to clarify this is not a homework question, I am genuinely curious. I have edited the question to explain a bit more what I'm asking.

Comment: After your edit: remember that velocities are *not* additive in special relativity.